# Most efficient way to name a user avatar?

Tags: php

I want to let my users upload an avatar on their profile. My first idea was to name the avatar file like this: [user_id].jpg. So even if a user updates its avatar, it keeps the same name.

The problem with that is that if I use caching on the server (or even if it's used on the client) the new avatar won't show up.

My new solution is to name the file like this:

[user_id]_[random_number].jpg

and store the random number in the Users table. How would you generate this number in the most efficient way? Or maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: I assume `user_id` is a number?

Comment: @ Grzegorz: yes, the actual id of the users table. Now I see that people are advising against showing the id publicly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
$avatarName = $userId . uniqid();
// add extension if needed, store it
```

It will be fast and do what you want. [uniqid()](http://php.net/uniqid)

**EDIT**

As suggested by other users, you should drop the userId from the image name. Having a public userId may lead to problems in the future. 
Also, `uniqid()` alone should work.

```
$avatarName = uniqid();
// add extension if needed, store it
```

Comment: I agree. I was just following OP idea. Edited accordingly.

Comment: I'm using the $userId publicly at different places in my app. Is there a reason why it should be hidden? On SO if I click on your profile I get an id in the URL:333893. Isn't it your userid? Or is it a different field?

Comment: @Max: To be honest, there shouldn't be any problem as long as you care about sql injections and that kind of stuff around your app (I can't recall any other reason atm). Anyway, why do you need `$userId` at your file's name? Any reason I can think of will be useless once you add something random to it.

Comment: ok thanks! Actually I like your solution. I don't think I need the user_id in the filename. I was just worried about my other pieces of code (I use a URL structure similar to SO) :)

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to invalidate the cache when the user uploads a new avatar.

If this is not possible you could just store it as [uid]_[YYYYMMDDhhmmss].jpg or something. No need to generate anything random...

Comment: Unless you want to hide the `uid` from other users who could possibly take advantage of having someone's uid.

Comment: Sure.. OP should probably just use uniqid() . ".jpg"; and then store the current avatar-filename in the user model.

Comment: @Jorge: I'm using the $userId publicly at different places in my app. Is there a reason why it should be hidden? On SO if I click on your profile I get an id in the URL:313194. Isn't it your userid? Or is it a different field?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about configuring [ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) in your .htaccess?

See:

http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_11/

Though you can change filenames, you will need to manage the cleanup and pointing operations (remove/rename the old file, tell your app the new file). If you are happy to do this, you can simply append the users id with the unix timestamp at the point of upload, its unlikely they will be able to upload the same file to the same second. If you want to make it even more unique, append a random number/uniquid.

Comment: I have never heard of this but I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

With a random number there is a miniscule (negligible) chance of a collision, but why not start at 1 and just increase the number each time since you are storing this number.

Comment: The problem is that I'd have to query the db each time to know which one is next. Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: You could just keep one master number for all users, you will still have to save it back to the database each time you used it.